# Parse json in node js

Tags: json, node.js

Can someone help me with this json {"event":"update","data":"{\"asks\":[[\"55.5\",\"5.3744\"],[\"55.74\",\"0.8087\"]]}}, how parse this values from json 55.5 and 5.3744. I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid and cannot be parsed.

I assume your `data` is a JSON string within a JSON string that should be parsed after the main JSON string has been parsed. This is not really efficient and you should consider not stringifying the `data` value in the first place.

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{"event":"update","data":{"asks":[["55.5","5.3744"],["55.74","0.8087"]]}}
```

Or:

```
{\"event\":\"update\",\"data\":{\"asks\":[[\"55.5\",\"5.3744\"],[\"55.74\",\"0.8087\"]]}}
```

In JavaScript:

```
const json = '{"event":"update","data":{"asks":[["55.5","5.3744"],["55.74","0.8087"]]}}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
const val1 = obj.data.asks[0][0];
const val2 = obj.data.asks[0][1];
```

If you *must* have `data` as a JSON encoded string, encode it correctly. If you want to know what your JSON string should look like in this case, work backwards:

```
const dataString = JSON.stringify({
    asks: [
        ["55.5", "5.3744"],
        ["55.74","0.8087"]
    ]
});

const jsonString = JSON.stringify({
    event: "update",
    data: dataString
});

// {\"event\":\"update\",\"data\":\"{\\\"asks\\\":[[\\\"55.5\\\",\\\"5.3744\\\"],[\\\"55.74\\\",\\\"0.8087\\\"]]}\"}

// And back again...

const asks = JSON.parse(
    JSON.parse(jsonString).data
).asks;
const val1 = asks[0][0];
const val2 = asks[0][1];
```